# How to check if js variable exists?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I've got a few variables that I need to get from a global in another part of a big project.  Currently, I'm setting and defaulting the variables like this:

```
var identifier = Site.settings.urls.accountsUrl || 'https://staging.mysite.com';
```

The idea is that Site doesn't exist on my dev instance, but it should be used dynamically in prod. So in dev, the Site object is always undefined.  Works well like this and the browser doesn't complain, but jshint will let me know that Site is undefined.  Is there a better way to do this?  I know this is a bit subjective, but I'm interested to see responses.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that's gonna cause a runtime error if `Site` isn't defined.

Comment: I wish I didn't have to use a global, but sometimes you do.  Doesn't seem to cause a runtime error.

Comment: Actually, just did a sanity check and the statement above does not define the fallback.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  Gonna go with Richie's suggestion, as I think its the most efficient and readable.  A bit ugly, but so was the duckling. Peace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if (typeof Site === 'undefined') {
    // There is no Site.
}
```

but it's a bit ugly.

How about defining a global at the very start that means "I am the Dev instance", and then overriding it in the Prod instance with a value meaning "I am the Prod instance"?  At least that way the variable always exists.

Comment: That's actually how I did it originally, but it was a bit ugly, because of the required else condition.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be something like this...

```
try {
    var identifier = Site.settings.urls.accountsUrl
}
catch (e) {
    var identifier = 'https://staging.mysite.com'
}
```

Basically, we always try to set the `identifier` to the URL, but will default to the second value if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a one-liner **and** if `Site` is never defined without `settings.*`, you can do this:

```
var identifier = window.Site && Site.settings.urls.accountsUrl || 'https://staging.mysite.com';
```

Though, it may make more sense to have `Site.settings.url.accountsUrl` *always* be defined. Create a default configuration file. Include that file at the top of the page. And include overrides directly after.

---

JavaScript also supports the ternary operator, if you feel that's safer and/or prettier:

```
var identifier = typeof(Site) == 'undefined' ? 'https://staging.mysite.com' : Site.settings.urls.accountsUrl;
```

Comment: I like the ternary, but jshint doesn't. =)